# Append characters to new page in `docx` document

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I am trying to append a string to the end of a `docx` document in a new page.

Here is the code I use now:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path/fname, true))

var body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
var para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
var run = para.AppendChild(new Run());

var txt = "Document Signed by User" + Environment.NewLine;
run.AppendChild(new Text(txt));
```

But it appends the text in the end of the document and not in a new page.

**Edit**

Used the solution proposed by Daniel A. White:

```
var para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
var run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
var plc = run.AppendChild(new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page });
var txt = "Document Signed by User: " + user.User" + Environment.NewLine;
plc.AppendChild(new Text(txt));
```

But I got this error :

> Non-composite elements do not have child elements

Comment: Your example seems to be missing `{` and `}` around the `using` statement.

Comment: don't append to the break, just keep appending to your run.

Comment: @DanielA.White thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a `Break` into your `Run` with `Type` set to `BreakValues.Page`.

```
run.AppendChild(new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page });
```

Comment: I receive this error if I try that : Non-composite elements do not have child elements